# Where can I find the source code of some empty Ansible core modules?

Tags: python, ansible

I can't figure out how to find the source code of some Ansbile core modules.

For example, modules [`fetch`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/files/fetch.py), [`template`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/files/template.py), [`debug`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/utilities/logic/debug.py) or [`fail`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/utilities/logic/fail.py) don't have any code in their respective Python file. Only the documentation and some meta-data are there.

I guess these modules are implemented in the core engine, but I can't find the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These modules are implemented as [action plugins](https://www.ansible.com/blog/how-to-extend-ansible-through-plugins), you can find all of them here:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action

The difference to other modules is that they are first (or solely) executed on the controller machine.